# I am making a discord bot and have it check if a message sender is itself but I get: NameError: name 'message' is not defined

Tags: discord.py

I have this

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(self):

    # don't respond to ourselves
    if message.author == self.user:

        return

    if message.content == 'ping':

        await message.channel.send('pong')
```

I have tried changing `message.author` to `str(message.author)` but it still gives NameError: name 'message' is not defined

Comment: What do you expect the value of the `message` variable to be, and where would that come from? I don't know discord's API, but does the method maybe need to be declared as `on_message(self, message)`?

Comment: A quick google search shows that, yes: you either need a top-level function declared as `on_message(message)` or an instance method `on_message(self, message)`: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html

Comment: Doing that fixed the error I was getting, but now I'm getting "Error: on_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'"

Comment: Do you use this in a cog or Class? If yes You need on_message(self,message)
and in most cases self.user is self.bot but it depends on how you named your variable.

Comment: Sorry, I solved this. The problem was somewhere else in the code. I was using example.example instead of bot.example